# Strange error when trying to get data from database in another file

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I was trying to get count of items in databases. Getting count with second database is working as planned, but the first one is giving me this error
`KeyError: <weakref at 0x000001E85C863330; to "Flask" at 0x000001E8397750D0>`
This program is a very simplified, but removed elements are working fine(Get, Post, Delete methods...)

So I have 3 files
**server1:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///emp.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Value(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class GetCount(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def count():
        count = Value.query.count()
        return count
```

**server2:**

```
app2 = Flask(__name__)

api2 = Api(app2)

app2.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///emp2.db'
app2.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db2 = SQLAlchemy(app2)


class Value2(db2.Model):
    id = db2.Column(db2.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db2.Column(db2.Integer, nullable=False)

class GetCount2(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def count():
        count = Value2.query.count()
        return count
```

**masternode:**

```
import time
from server1 import app, Value
from server2 import app2, Value2

app.app_context().push()
app2.app_context().push()

while True:
    c = Value.query.count()
    c2 = Value2.query.count()
    print(c, c2)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I was trying to start this program, but got the error mentioned above. But when I deleted
`c = Value.query.count()`
from **masternode** file I got expected result(1 1 1 1 and so on)

So I really don't understand why one program is working and other is not when they are practically the same

Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\Домашка\FlaskTest\masternode.py", line 15, in <module>
    c1 = Value.query.count()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3175, in count
    return self._from_self(col).enable_eagerloads(False).scalar()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2892, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2869, in one
    return self._iter().one()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2915, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1702, in execute
    bind = self.get_bind(**bind_arguments)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\session.py", line 61, in get_bind
    engines = self._db.engines
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 629, in engines
    return self._app_engines[app]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\weakref.py", line 415, in __getitem__
    return self.data[ref(key)]
           ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: <weakref at 0x000001E85C863330; to 'Flask' at 0x000001E8397750D0>
```

Comment: Since names of variables and classes don't matter by themselves, the only difference between the two scripts you shared is the `'sqlite:///emp2.db'` value. So, unless there's some substantial difference there, the problem is likely somewhere in the code you left out and the problem cannot be reproduced with the information you provided.

Comment: @Grismar I really don't know what to add. The only thing I can say that in my Delete method(which is not mentioned above) is the dame line of code (Value.query.count()) and it is working normally for both databases. I really don't know how to describe this problem in another words because everything in server1 and server2 is the same except for databases but somehow despite all methods like Get, Post... and count for second database are working normally, count for first just gives me error described above

Comment: This is a guess, but flask uses app contexts to determine the current app, and  it looks to me as if (1) app2 is the current app (most recently pushed context) (2) the error is that `app` cannot be found.  So perhaps you need to run the queries in their respective contexts and then merge the results?

Comment: That said, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74134089/5320906) is similar, and the problem was with app initialisation.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes, moving app_context right before doing something with Value.query.count() solved my issue. Maybe you can do this is a post so I could mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask uses app [contexts](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/appcontext/#the-application-context) to determine the current app, so queries for different apps should be run in their respective contexts.

Something like this ought to work:

```py
while True:
    with app.app_context():
        c = Value.query.count()
    with app2.app_context:
        c2 = Value2.query.count()
    print(c, c2)
    time.sleep(1)
```