# KeyError: WeakRef when using flask-sqlalchemy version 3

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have seen similar answers to this but have not come across any concrete answer. Since upgrading my `Flask-SQLAlchemy` version from 2.5.1 to 3.0.2, I am encountering the following error anytime I try to query or do any database operations: `KeyError: <weakref at 0x10ed004a0; to 'Flask' at 0x10cb5d880>`

My application setup is nearly identical to the one outlined [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#configure-the-extension)

```
application = Flask(
    __name__, instance_path=instance_path, instance_relative_config=True
)

if configurations.PRODUCTION:
    application.config.from_pyfile("production.py")
else:
    application.config.from_pyfile("local.py")

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(application)

@application.route("/injury")
def get_injury_by_id():
    return db.session.query(Injury).filter_by(id=1).first()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Anytime I try and access this `db` object to try and run queries on its session, the error stated previously arises. I have tried playing around with the ordering of my initialization, such as by just doing

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app=application)
```

But everything seems to be throwing this error. I reverted my version back to 2.5.1 and can confirm this was working up until 3.0.2.

Any suggestions?

**Edit** Full stack trace after doing a query like `db.session.query(Injury).filter_by(id=1).first()` shown in the API route above

```
[2022-12-28 16:19:35,676...application...ERROR]: The following error occurred 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Desktop/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Desktop/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Desktop/project/backend/application.py", line 47, in get_injury_by_name
    return session.query(Injury).filter_by(id=1).first()
  File "/Desktop/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2819, in first
    return self.limit(1)._iter().first()
  File "/Desktop/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2903, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "/Desktop/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1700, in execute
    bind = self.get_bind(**bind_arguments)
  File "/Desktop/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/session.py", line 61, in get_bind
    engines = self._db.engines
  File "/Desktop/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 629, in engines
    return self._app_engines[app]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/weakref.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    return self.data[ref(key)]
KeyError: <weakref at 0x10f400540; to 'Flask' at 0x10d31c880>
'
```

Another thing to note is if I make a dummy file for testing purposes that looks like such

```
with application.app_context():
    db.session.query(Injury).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
```

The query executes properly.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback, please?

Comment: Before others downvote - this issue seems to have cropped up a few times and there doesn't seem to be a clear answer. It looks like something changed with the SQLAlchemy API that isn't well known

Comment: In support of roganjosh's comment, it would be good to get a [mre] to reliably reproduce this. For example [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74512773/5320906) provides enough information to obtain answer.

Comment: Thank you, I added the stack trace. Will try a minimal repro example as well

Comment: When executing your querys are you in the app context? are you using the `with app.app_context` decorator? Try to show what is exactly the line of code that produces the error and share it with us.

Comment: @SebastianSalinasDelRio Updated my example. This is occurring when I am accessing an endpoint defined by my flask application so it doesn't seem like I would need `app.app_context()` since this is within the context of the current application

Comment: It looks like you are trying to return a SQLAlchemy result object when you should be returning a Response, this could be from make_response, render_template, a dictionary that will be transformed in to json or plain text.

Comment: @SebastianSalinasDelRio it really seems like you're stabbing in the dark

Comment: I don't believe this has to do with returning a SQLAlchemy object. This is occurring anywhere I am trying to interact with the database. I think it has to do with [this](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/1087) PR.

Comment: It's too late for me to make meaningful progress on this tonight. My _suspicion_ (my own shot in the dark) would be down to a change in how connections are handled in threads <insert furious hand-waving here>; I'm not sure I've seen weakrefs like this in the wild. But, I'll try pick it up tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh, I'll try digging through that PR I just linked to see if I can find anything.

Comment: That's a PR on the `flask-sqlalchemy` side, but don't forget that it requires an upgrade to sqla 3.x for the issue to manifest, so it's unlikely to be the sole cause of the problem

Comment: Can you share a sample configuration? Running the code with a minimal config (sqlalchemy database uri) does not reproduce the error.  Similarly, are the extra parameters to `Flask()` required to reproduce the problem?